# How to pass a dataframe slice to histogram function for mode normalisation in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram, slice, normalization

I want to normalise selected columns of a dataframe by a user defined normalisation. So far I am going with

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Mode <- function(x, na.rm =  TRUE) {
  x <- lapply(x, as.numeric)
  distribution <- hist(x, breaks = 50, plot = FALSE)
  distribution$mids[which.max(distribution$counts)]
}

data_normalised <- lapply(mtcars[,-9:-12], function(x) {(x-Mode(x))/(sd(x))})
```

as minimal example.
However, hist is complaining that "x must be numeric". I thought this could be solved by casting

```
x <- lapply(x, as.numeric)
```

which does not work.
I know that hist works for

```
hist(mtcars[[3]])
```

but I cannot find a way to combine df slicing and hist function, as

```
hist(mtcars[[-9:-12]])
```

won't work eighter.

Idealy I would want the Mode() function to work as the sd() function. Take a df column and give back a value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your function `Mode` doesn't return anything; you should add `return()' and the value you are interested in, before ending the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `Mode()` function, `class(x)` is `'numeric'` (i.e. you have a numeric vector of length 32). Then you use `lapply()` to apply the function `as.numeric()` to `x`. After this step, `class(x)` is `'list'` Since as.numeric is vectorised, you don't actually loop through the elements of the vector, instead you can just use `x <- as.numeric(x)` in the mode function:

```
Mode <- function(x, na.rm =  TRUE) {
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  distribution <- hist(x, breaks = 50, plot = FALSE)
  distribution$mids[which.max(distribution$counts)]
}
```

You can then proceed as you did and it will not produce errors:

```
data_normalised <- lapply(mtcars[,-9:-12], function(x) {(x-Mode(x))/(sd(x))})
```

If you want to get a data.frame again, you can use `cbind()`:

```
data_normalised <- do.call("cbind", data_normalised)
```

And you get:

```
head(data_normalised)
           mpg         cyl      disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs
[1,] 0.9540484 -1.09187321 0.6858229  0.03646289  1.54298263 -0.84827399 -0.35815351 -0.01984063
[2,] 0.9540484 -1.09187321 0.6858229  0.03646289  1.54298263 -0.58765969 -0.04476919 -0.01984063
[3,] 1.2527070 -2.21174317 0.2662607 -0.21148473  1.44946853 -1.15487905  0.84501845  1.96422286
[4,] 1.0204170 -1.09187321 1.4765365  0.03646289  0.00935141 -0.24017396  1.30949879  1.96422286
[5,] 0.5724290  0.02799675 2.2995240  0.98449790  0.14027115 -0.01022017 -0.04476919 -0.01984063
[6,] 0.4728762 -1.09187321 1.2102758 -0.03646289 -0.58913882  0.01022017  1.74599838  1.96422286
```

Comment: Works excellent! Thank you! Problably I did not understand some underlying concepts here. I think the lappy already gives a dataframe back.